# Running hasktags for plenty of .hs source files for getting CTAGS File (plain Windows)

Tags: emacs, haskell, ctags

I want to produce a ETAGS file with hasktags, for that I can use it within Emacs with M-. (Find Tag).

I am using Emacs running on Windows. Since I have no MSYS/Cygwin installed, i I cannot do

```
find -name \*\*hs | xargs hasktags
```

How may I generate hasktags ETAGS files for a plenty of .hs source files?

Best regards

Comment: having cygwin means having xargs... :-)

Answer (score 3):

In `cmd.exe`,

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /b /s *.hs') do hasktags "%i"
```

Change `%i` to `%%i` in a batch script (`.bat`/`.cmd`).

In PowerShell,

```
Get-ChildItem -Include '*.hs' -Recurse | Foreach-Object {hasktags $_}
```

But of course, you could have just written a simple Haskell program to do this (or used GHCi), starting from [Real World Haskell - I/O case study: a library for searching the filesystem](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html) or [System.FilePath.Find](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filemanip/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Find.html), and adding in [`system`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Cmd.html#v%3asystem) to call `hasktags`.

Comment: Actually, not having used `hasktags` myself, I'm not sure if it does the right thing when invoked once per file rather than on all the files at once.  If so, the batch/PS methods get trickier, but the Haskell way remains easy :)

Comment: Can we get hasktags to actually support recursive generation natively? Please? :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers. Ephemient script (cmd.exe) is runing - the protocol looks very good - but hasktags is not appending on my windows machine, i don't get "-a" (append) running correctly. When I ommit "-a" it is overwriting, when I add "-a" it is keeping the file as it is (if there is a file - otherwise its doing nothing)...

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang fyi, starting with `hasktags-0.68.2` recursive traversal is supported natively...